# How to split a polygon into quadrants in R/Qgis?

Tags: qgis, r, polygon-creation

I am solving the same problem as [How to split a polygon into quadrants?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/42629/4630), except that I am looking for a solution in R or QGis. So I have a polygon layer shapefile, which is unfortunatelly not *exactly* rectangular (due to some reprojections etc.). I would like to split the "squares" into 2x2, 4x4 or 8x8 smaller squares, as equal as possible.

[image]

Note that I am not looking for tool to *generate* a new grid, but to split the one I already have.

Comment: In QGIS, I don't think there's a built-in function to "split" polygons into your desired dimensions. If via the interface then you would have to create a new grid, clip your polygon layer onto it and then use **Join by location**. I'm fairly certain it's possible to do this from **R** or writing a python script in QGIS if you know your coding but hopefully others can advise.

Comment: Thanks @Joseph, I don't think this is a good solution, the square net is little bit irregular so each polygon should be divided separately so that we get it split into sub-squares as-equal-as-possible. I will wait for other advices.

Comment: No problem @Thomas, a final question. Couldn't you **Dissolve** the polygon layer first to remove all "squares" and then do those steps mentioned? Or must the "squares" remain at their exact location?

Comment: @Joseph please see the last sentence of my question.

Comment: Ahh...don't know how I missed that!

Comment: Can you share your layer ?

Answer (score 2):

[Here I address the question in detail](https://www.modlearth.com/2022/09/23/subgrid/). Here I cover the problem in detail. In resume I propose two ways.

## Option 1 - simple way

If you dont need the lines to be coincident among polygons what you can do is this:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

layer <- read_sf('./data/20220923/A.gpkg')
layer$id <- rownames(layer)
# mapview(layer)
# set number of divisions
div <- 4
ls <- list()
for (i in 1:nrow(layer)){
    x <- st_make_grid(layer[i,], n = div) %>% st_as_sf() # divide pol
    xx <- st_intersection(layer[i,], x) # intersection
    xx$id <- layer[i,]$id 
    ls[[i]] <- xx
}

l2 <- sf::st_as_sf(data.table::rbindlist(ls)) # superfast
# mapview(l2)+layer
```

Layer looks like this:
[image]

And then you have it with a 4x4 subdivision example:
[image]

## Option 2 - complex way (better results)

If you need the subdivision lines to be coincident you can follow the process in the link with the steps explained. The function has a paramenter for the number of divisions `div''. Here is the code in case you just what to try it:

```
# This functions is made to short coords clock wise (implemented inside QuasiRectangularSpliter)
sortcoords <- function(x){
    # sort points to construct lines clock wise lines
    # 1. Upper left corner: from the 2 leftest points, take the upper one
    # 2. Upper right corner: ...
    # 3. Bottom right corner: ...
    # 4. Bottom left corner: ...
    # 5. Close coord = 1
    x <- unique(x)
    x1 <- ((as.data.frame(x) %>% arrange(X))[1:2,] %>% arrange(desc(Y)))[1,]
    x2 <- ((as.data.frame(x) %>% arrange(desc(X)))[1:2,] %>% arrange(desc(Y)))[1,]
    x3 <- ((as.data.frame(x) %>% arrange(desc(X)))[1:2,] %>% arrange(Y))[1,]
    x4 <- ((as.data.frame(x) %>% arrange(X))[1:2,] %>% arrange(Y))[1,]
    x5 <- x1
    do.call(rbind, list(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5)) %>% as.matrix()
}

QuasiRectangularSpliter <- function(layer, div = 4, adjust = 0.5){
    subpolygons <- list()
    for (poly in 1:nrow(layer)){
        # poly <- 2 # funcional
        # poly <- 9 # erratico
        # cat('Creating subpolygons for ', poly, ' of ', nrow(layer), '\n')
        # Create coords
        pol <- layer[poly,]
        xx <- st_cast(pol, "LINESTRING")
        xx <- st_node(xx)

        x <- st_cast(xx, "POINT")
        x <- x %>% st_coordinates()
        x <- sortcoords(x)
        
        # Create lines
        ls <- list()
        for (i in 1:4){
            # i <- 1
            x1 <- x[i, 1]
            x2 <- x[i+1, 1]
            y1 <- x[i, 2]
            y2 <- x[i+1, 2]
            lcoord <- matrix(c(x1,x2,y1,y2), 2)
            l <- st_linestring(lcoord) %>% st_sfc() %>% st_as_sf()
            l$id <- pol$id
            ls[[i]] <- l
        }
        
        l2 <- sf::st_as_sf(data.table::rbindlist(ls)) # superfast
        st_crs(l2) <- st_crs(pol)
        # mapview(l2, color = "red")+layer
        
        # Create point for lines
        lsample <- seq(0, 1, by=1/div) # seq for st_line_sample
        
        ps <- list()
        for(i in 1:4){
            p <- st_line_sample(l2[i,], type = "regular", sample = lsample) %>%
                st_cast("POINT") %>% st_sfc() %>% st_as_sf()
            
            # CORRECTION to be sure about creating totally overlaping lines:
            if(i == 1){ # points in horizontal upper line --> y+1
                st_geometry(p) <- st_geometry(p) + c(0, adjust)
            } else if (i == 2){ # points in vertical right line --> x+1
                st_geometry(p) <- st_geometry(p) + c(adjust, 0)
            } else if (i == 3){ # points in bottom horizontal line --> y-1
                st_geometry(p) <- st_geometry(p) + c(0, -adjust)
            } else { # points in left vertical line --> x-1
                st_geometry(p) <- st_geometry(p) + c(-adjust, 0)
            }
            
            # return
            ps[[i]] <- p
        }
        
        # Create vertical lines
        vlines <- list()
        for(i in 1:(div+1)){
            p1 <- ps[[1]][i,]
            p2 <- ps[[3]][div+2-i, ]
            lcoord <- rbind(st_coordinates(p1), st_coordinates(p2))
            l <- st_linestring(lcoord) %>% st_sfc() %>% st_as_sf()
            l$id <- pol$id
            vlines[[i]] <- l
        }
        
        # Create horizontal lines
        hlines <- list()
        for(i in 1:(div+1)){
            p1 <- ps[[4]][div+2-i,]
            p2 <- ps[[2]][i, ]
            lcoord <- rbind(st_coordinates(p1), st_coordinates(p2))
            l <- st_linestring(lcoord) %>% st_sfc() %>% st_as_sf()
            l$id <- pol$id
            hlines[[i]] <- l
        }
        
        # merge layers
        v2 <- sf::st_as_sf(data.table::rbindlist(vlines)) # superfast
        h2 <- sf::st_as_sf(data.table::rbindlist(hlines)) # superfast
        st_crs(v2) <- st_crs(pol)
        st_crs(h2) <- st_crs(pol)
        mapview(v2)+h2+pol
        
        lgrid <- rbind(v2, h2)
        polygons <- lgrid %>% st_cast("MULTILINESTRING")
        polygons = st_collection_extract(st_polygonize(st_union(polygons))) %>%
            st_as_sf()
        polygons$id = pol$id
        polygons <- st_cast(polygons, "MULTIPOLYGON")
        
        # add polygons to list
        subpolygons[[poly]] <- polygons
        
        # mapview(polygons)+v2+h2+pol
    }
    # merge layers
    mergedpols <- sf::st_as_sf(data.table::rbindlist(subpolygons)) # superfast

    # return
    mergedpols
}

# let's try it:
l4 <- QuasiRectangularSpliter(layer, 4)
mapview(l4)
```

[image]

As you can see here, ***lines are following the not exactly rectangular shape and are connected among polygons***. You can iterate over it or tweak it to make other levels of subdivisions.